# Why is it important to never charge a cell at voltage higher than Vmax?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion

In specifications for Li-ion cells, the maximum charging voltage (Vmax) is typically given and said that the cell must not be charged at a voltage higher than that.

If I understand correctly, there are two reasons why charging a Li-ion cell at a voltage higher than Vmax can degrade or destabilise the cell:

- If we charge at this voltage long enough the cell will over-charge (Vmax assumed to be equal or close to OCV(SoC = 100%))
- The difference Vmax – OCV(SoC = 0%) is high enough to make some unwanted reactions at the electrode-electrolyte interface(s) possible, or alternatively, the current = (Vmax – OCV(SoC = 0%))/Rchg is high enough to cause some damage to the battery. (Though, the maximum charging current Imax could also be specified directly.)

(For simplicity, I also assume the cell's internal voltage consists only of the OCV.)

If this is right, I don't see what could go wrong if I charge a cell at a voltage higher than Vmax at the moment when it's at SoC = 70%, for example. Assuming the Imax of the cell is in the order of hundreds of Amperes because otherwise, it probably limits my charging voltage to a value lower than Vmax even at SoC = 70%.

So one explanation I can see for why cell manufacturers give "simplified" instructions about Vmax is that they also specify Imax in the order of single-digit Amperes (translates to single-digit C-rates). This means that at the normal temperature when the Rchg is single-digit mOhm, we are never allowed to charge at a voltage more than about the current OCV voltage + 0.05 V. This means that the theoretical time window when we would be able to charge at a voltage higher than Vmax is too small to bother specifying it.

If the above explanation is correct, then I don't understand why the cell's available charging power is calculated as Vmax*(OCV - Vmax)/Rchg: in practice, this charging power should be prohibited almost all of the time?

Comment: "I don't see what could go wrong" An annoying tendency to burst into unextinguishable [fire](https://youtu.be/-DcpANRFrI4).

Comment: Can you clarify what is the question really? If a battery has 4.0V voltage at 70% charge of state, and you want to charge it with some constant current, then the battery charger is in constant current mode to avoid damage from too high current and voltage will be 4.0V as that is what the battery has. When battey is charged enough that less current than the limit goes into the battery, the charger switches to constant voltage mode which is limited to 4.2V to avoid damage to battery. If you simply applied 4.2V to an empty battery, too much current would flow, limited by wires and ESR.

Comment: You can't "charge a cell at a voltage higher than Vmax at the moment when it's at SoC = 70%" because the battery isn't at Vmax when SoC is 70%. Connecting a voltage source with a voltage higher than Vmax would result in a very high current into the battery and could cause interesting fireworks.

Comment: @ocrdu ok, then my theory about Imax in single-digit Amperes max current looks right. Then I don't understand where does the max available charging power formula come from, because it should rather probably be Imax^2/Rchg 99% of the time.

Comment: I don't think the title of your question is in fact the question you want answered. You should change it to reflect what you really want to ask to get useful commentary.